# XSLT: Suggest for otherwise code, while all 'when' conditions are not met

Tags: xslt

Please suggest, I am working on MathML code, in 'subsup' element, it should have three elements. But my previous scripts are inserted some space tags after the 'sub' or 'subsup' elements (that is required for internal process). By this existing 'subsup' will have more than three child. However all conditions I wrote, but unable to code the 'Otherwise' code, if none of the 'when' conditions are not met. If space found, then my code will enclose 'space and following or precedings' with one 'mrow', by that ensuring the msubsup having three childs only.

XML:

```
    <article>
 <body>
 <p>Graphene <inline-formula>
 <math>
 <mtext>yyyy</mtext>
    <msubsup>
        <mi>H</mi>
        <mn>1</mn>
        <mn>2</mn>
    </msubsup>
    <msubsup>
        <mi>A</mi>
        <mspace width="0.04"/>
        <mn>1</mn>
        <mspace width="0.04"/>
        <mn>2</mn>
        <mspace width="0.04"/>
      <mn>2</mn>
    </msubsup>
    <msubsup>
       <mi>B</mi>
       <mn>1</mn>
       <mspace width="0.04"/>
       <mn>2</mn>
       <mspace width="0.04"/>
    </msubsup>
    <msubsup>
      <mi>C</mi>
      <mn>1</mn>
      <mn>7</mn>
      <mspace width="0.04"/>
    </msubsup>
    <msubsup>
      <mi>D</mi>
      <mn>1</mn>
      <mn>2</mn>
      <mspace width="0.04"/>
    </msubsup>
    <msubsup>
      <mi>E</mi>
      <mspace width="0.04"/>
      <mn>1</mn>
      <mspace width="0.04"/>
      <mn>2</mn>
    </msubsup>
 </math>
 <inline-graphic xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="fdr495521ieqn220a39.gif"/>
 </inline-formula>
 </p>
 </body>
 </article>
```

XSLT:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
       <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="msubsup[count(child::*) &gt; 3]">
      <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:for-each select="*"><!--Cheking with each child, grouping mspace with preceded or followed element, ensuring three child with subsup element-->
           <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="position()=1 and name()='mspace' and not(following-sibling::*[name()='mspace'])"><!--Child 1 having space, then it has to enclose by 'mrow' with immediate following element-->
                  <xsl:element name="mrow">
                       <xsl:apply-templates select="self::node()"/>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>
                  </xsl:element>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[2]"/>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[3]"/>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[4]"/>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[5]"/>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[6]"/>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[7]"/>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="position()=2 and name()='mspace' and not(following-sibling::*[name()='mspace'])"><!--Child 2 having space, then it has to enclose by 'mrow' with immediate preceding element-->
                  <xsl:element name="mrow">
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="preceding-sibling::*"/>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="self::node()"/>
                  </xsl:element>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*|node()"/>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="position()=2 and name()='mspace' and following-sibling::*[2][name()='mspace']">
                  <xsl:element name="mrow">
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="preceding-sibling::*"/>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="self::node()"/>
                  </xsl:element>
                  <xsl:element name="mrow">
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[2]"/>
                  </xsl:element>
                  <xsl:element name="mrow">
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[3]"/>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[4]"/>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[5]"/>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[6]"/>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[7]"/>
                  </xsl:element>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="position()=2 and name()='mspace' and following-sibling::*[3][name()='mspace']">
                  <xsl:element name="mrow">
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="preceding-sibling::*"/>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="self::node()"/>
                  </xsl:element>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>
                  <xsl:element name="mrow">
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[2]"/>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[3]"/>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[4]"/>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[5]"/>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[6]"/>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[7]"/>
                  </xsl:element>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="position()=3 and name()='mspace' and not(preceding-sibling::*[name()='mspace'])">
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="preceding-sibling::*[2]"/>
                  <xsl:element name="mrow">
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="preceding-sibling::*[1]"/>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="self::node()"/>
                  </xsl:element>
                  <xsl:element name="mrow">
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*|node()"/>
                  </xsl:element>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="(position()=4 or position() &gt; 4) and name()='mspace' and not(preceding-sibling::*[name()='mspace'])">
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="preceding-sibling::*[3]"/>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="preceding-sibling::*[2]"/>
                  <xsl:element name="mrow">
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="preceding-sibling::*[1]"/>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="self::node()"/>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*|node()"/>
                  </xsl:element>
              </xsl:when>
              <!--Please suggest, what may be the 'otherwise' code if top all 'when' conditions not met-->
              <!--xsl:otherwise>
                   <xsl:apply-templates select="self::node()"/>
              </xsl:otherwise-->
          </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Required code: See my xsl, suggest for 'Otherwise' code. I am using XSL2 version

Required OutPut:

```
enter code here    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<article>
<body>
<p>Graphene <inline-formula>
<math>
<mtext>yyyy</mtext>
<msubsup>
  <mi>H</mi>
  <mn>1</mn>
  <mn>2</mn>
</msubsup>
<msubsup>
   <mrow>
    <mi>A</mi>
    <mspace width="0.04"/>
   </mrow>
   <mrow>
     <mn>1</mn>
     <mspace width="0.04"/>
   </mrow>
   <mrow>
    <mn>2</mn>
    <mspace width="0.04"/>
    <mspace width="0.04"/>
   <mn>2</mn>
   </mrow>
</msubsup>
<msubsup>
  <mi>B</mi>
  <mrow>
  <mn>1</mn>
  <mspace width="0.04"/>
  </mrow>
  <mrow>
  <mn>2</mn>
  <mspace width="0.04"/>
  </mrow>
</msubsup>
<msubsup>
<mi>C</mi>
<mn>1</mn>
<mrow>
<mn>7</mn>
<mspace width="0.04"/>
</mrow>
</msubsup>
<msubsup>
<mi>D</mi>
<mn>1</mn>
<mrow>
<mn>2</mn>
<mspace width="0.04"/>
</mrow>
</msubsup>
<msubsup>
<mrow>
<mi>E</mi>
<mspace width="0.04"/>
</mrow>
<mrow>
<mn>1</mn>
<mspace width="0.04"/>
</mrow>
<mrow>
<mn>2</mn>
</mrow>
</msubsup>
</math>
<inline-graphic xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="fdr495521ieqn220a39.gif"/>
</inline-formula>
</p>
</body>
</article>
```

Comment: Can you show the desired XML output?

Comment: See the required output file (many 'when' conditions I coded), my request is, if none of the when conditions are met, what is "xsl:otherwise" code for this.

Comment: Subsup should have three child, if mspace found and first position, then <mrow><mspace><next element/></mrow>, if mspace found at second position then mrow><first child><mspace/></mrow>, third poistion onwords everything will be in <mrow>third position space with rest of elements</mrow>.